# Auto Increment Number in Rename (Maya Python)

Tags: python, pyqt, maya

Trying to create a function that increments the value of the number entered in my Gui. The function is

```
def autoIncrement(self):
    myNumber = int(self.windowObj.myInt.value()) #This is my QSpinBox and it's value.
    selection = cmds.ls(sl=True) #List selected
    global myNumber #Setting the global
    start = myNumber #Setting the value to be QSpinBox's value. 
    interval = 1 # Adding 1 interval
    for object in selection:
        if (myNumber==0):
            myNumber= start
        else:
            myNumber = myNumber + interval #Needs to get the value in my spin box and add +1 to it for the next object selected.
            cmds.rename(object, myNumber)
```

What am I doing wrong? Keep in mind that my number being added in the middle of naming convention and want to avoid Maya to add one in the end. Current naming convention is 
NAME_NUMBER_POSITION_LEVEL
eg = MF_100_L_HI

```
Currently it renames but adds number at the end to:
MF_100_L_HI
MF_100_L_HI1
MF_100_L_HI2
When it should be like:
MF_100_L_HI
MF_101_L_HI
MF_102_L_HI

This is my renaming script:
def renamer(self):
    myNames = str(self.windowObj.myName.text()) # First field of text (e.g MF)
    myLevels= self.windowObj.myLevel.currentText() #Third feild of text (e.g HI)
    myPositions= self.windowObj.myPosition.currentText() #Fourth field text (e.g L)
    myNumbers= int(self.windowObj.myInt.value()) #Second field of text (The number goes here) (e.g 100)
    renamedName = (myNames + "_" + myNumbers + "_" + myPositions + "_" + myLevels)
    selection = cmds.ls(sl = True)

    for object in selection:
        cmds.rename(object, renamedName)
        print renamedName
```

Comment: Why do you have two scripts? Can you edit your question to show which method are you running and then what output you are getting?

Comment: Its the first one def autoIncrement

Comment: One more question, is the `object` variable a string like `MF_100__L_HI` representing the name of the object or its a real object? And another question, what is the value of the global `myNumber` variable?